# Aspects targeting WinForm project's methods are not working

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, .net-assembly, postsharp

I have a solution with 3 projects. I made it as a test:

1) The **WinFormsProject** (setted as Main project): It is just a form that throws an exception when clicking a button. Before throwing the exception, it makes some assignations with an object of the class *Person* (who is in another assembly).

2) The **ConsoleProject**: It's another assembly with the same idea: it only plays a little with an object of the class *Person* and then throws an Exception.

3) The **AspectTest**: it's an assembly which has defined the class *Person* and an aspect (called *LogBoundary*) (inherited from *OnMethodBoundaryAspect*) who logs *OnEntry*(), *OnExit*(), *OnSuccess*() and *OnException*().

The three assemblies are configured through an "AspectInfo.cs" class to target every method but the "CompileGenerated" ones. So:

```
[assembly: LogBoundary()]
[assembly: LogBoundary(
    AttributeExclude = true,
    AttributePriority = 0,
    AttributeTargetMemberAttributes = MulticastAttributes.CompilerGenerated)]
```

The problem is that all methods in the assembly **AspectTest** are being logged, but the ones in **WinFormsProject** not. I have no idea why.

Some things to consider:

- Every assembly has a reference to *postsharp*. So every aspect is
  being correctly recognized by the compiler.
- If I set the **ConsoleProject** as the Main project, it works
  correctly. The problems comes only with **WinFormsProject**.
- **WinFormsProject** references **AspectTests** (of course!).
- **ConsoleProject** references **AspectTests** (of course!).
- There is no dependency between **WinFormsProject** and
  **ConsoleProject**.

Any help would be great, and if you still need some info about this, please ask me (I might forget to tell something).

Thanks!

Comment: Please verify whether PostSharp runs when you rebuild the project, the similar line should be in your build output: `: message : PostSharp 4.1 [4.1.21.0, postsharp.srv.4.0-x86.exe, CLR 4.0.30319.379893, Release] complete -- 0 errors, 0 warnings, processed in 1013 ms`. Also the *.csproj file should have this line: `<Import Project="..\packages\PostSharp.4.1.21\tools\PostSharp.targets" ...`

Comment: PostSharp integrates into the build process when you install the NuGet package. If PostSharp doesn't run during build, then you can try to reinstall the package.

Answer (score 1):

To introduce the aspects into your code, PostSharp needs to execute during build time after the main compilation step. This means that adding a reference to PostSharp.dll in your project is not enough - the build sequence of the project needs to be modified as well.

PostSharp automatically integrates into the build process when you install the NuGet package. If PostSharp doesn't run during build, then you can try to reinstall the package.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am a bit ashamed of the reason, but it might pass to anyone, so here's the problem and how I solved it.

The problem was: as I added the postsharp.dll as a reference manually and not with NuGet (because I had no internet on that moment) the references were ok, all compiled as expected, but as said, aspects didn't worked on the Winforms project. Maybe I missed to do something else.

The solution, therefore was so easy as to add postsharp through Nuget. Just that.

Now everything works. If someone has a better idea of the description of the problem, it would be good to know it. 
thanks, AlexD.

Comment: Glad my reply helped you, this can happen to anyone. Copied my comment to a new answer for a better visibility.